# Python script does not restart/retry loop

Tags: python, loops, selenium, exception

I have a Python script with a loop.
If the code cannot find a specified element: (driver.find_element_by_xpath), he should print: "No Button". And then he should restart the loop.

But when I run the code, it will print "No button" BUT then it continues the script instead of retry/loop.

```
not_found=True
while not_found:

    try:
        browser=browser.open(link)
    except HTTPError, e:
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
    except URLError, e:
        print 'Connection reset by peer'
        sys.stdout.write('\a')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        new=0
        time.sleep(5)


    search_k="just some text to look for"
    source="output.txt"

    if not search_string(search_k, source):
        print "this is a message reminder"       

        startstr='search text"'
        endstr='" />'
        file='output.txt'
        prijs=float(get_html_string(file,startstr,endstr))

        search_s="just some text in .txt"
        filez="blee.txt"
        search_z="texttt"
        search_q="texttttttt"

        if search_string(search_s, filez) and not search_string(search_z, filez) and not search_string(search_q, filez) and rule <= maxprijs:

            driver.get(link)
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='submit']")
                elem.click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print"No Button"              
                time.sleep(2)     
                new=0 #LOOP SCRIPT IGNORES?
```

Comment: What does 'restart the loop mean'?

Comment: @e4c5 The code executes from the beginning.

Comment: beginning of what? from line 1?

Comment: @e4c5 sorry for the misunderstanding, yes from line 1

Comment: well, that simply cannot be not with this code at any rate.

Comment: @e4c5 well, I already figured it out that it aint working. For that reason I am trying to find help.

Comment: More like you haven't read these https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146882/discussion-between-jesse-kraal-and-e4c5).